# Mongodb unset from array under condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have users collection like this:

```
[
{
    "_id": ObjectId("5f40feac77514e76dd49950b"),
    "name": "Max",
    "email": "test@test.us",
    "cart": {
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": ObjectId("5f40f79f3b324fbaf85567a5"),
                "cnt": 1
            },
            {
                "productId": ObjectId("somethingrandom"),
                "cnt": 2
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "_id": ObjectId("whatever"),
    "name": "John",
    "email": "test@test.us",
    "cart": {
        "products": [
            {
                "productId": ObjectId("5f40f79f3b324fbaf85567a5"),
                "cnt": 1
            },
            {
                "productId": ObjectId("somethingrandom2"),
                "cnt": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
]
```

I want to go through every product in cart in every user and delete from products items which match id.
I tried something like this:

```
const productId = new ObjectId('5f40f79f3b324fbaf85567a5');
await db.collection('users').updateMany({
    'cart.products.productId': productId
},{
    $unset:{
        'cart.products.':null ///i don't know what should be here
    }
});
```

I don't want to delete all products from cart, but only these which has the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`$pull`-operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) to accomplish this:

```
await db.collection('users').update(
    {},
    { $pull: { "cart.products": { productId } } },
    { multi: true }
});
```